# What is the minimum raw FLOPS that supercomputers need to be included in the Green500 list?

Tags: hpc

The [Green500 List](https://www.top500.org/green500/) lists the top 500 most energy efficient supercomputers.

My question is, what is the minimum FLOPS that computers need to be considered for the Green500 list?

Do they just take the TOP500 list and rank them according to FLOPS/watt (cut-off = FLOPS of the 500th computer of TOP500)? Or is there some other cut-off value?

If there were no such minimum, then it would make no sense, otherwise, say, cell phones, might as well be on the list.

I could compare both lists to see if they contain the same computers, but lazy.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [main page of Green500 List](https://www.top500.org/green500/):

> #### About the Green500 List
>
> **The Green500 list ranks the top 500 supercomputers in the world by energy efficiency**. ... To address this trend, the Green500 list puts a premium on energy-efficient performance for sustainable supercomputing.

Also, if you look at the list itself, say [June 2018](https://www.top500.org/green500/lists/2018/06/), the first column is Green500 rank, while the second one lists Top500 rank.

So, one can say that the overall procedure is the following:

1. First, the Top500 list is created based on the performance.
2. Then, power efficiency (GFlops/watts) is measured or derived. (the systems with derived efficiencies are shaded in the Green500 list).
3. Green500 list is created by sorting the participants of Top500 list by power efficiency.

So yeah, the cut-off is the 500th computer of TOP500.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, I wish they would phrase it in a way that would make that clearer.